# Android - Calling a function from a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a tabbed activity with 3 fragments. One of my fragments has got a button with is calling a function onClick:

```
<Button
    android:text="Start meeting"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:id="@+id/sp_live_meeting"
    android:layout_below="@+id/live_cost"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="sp_timer" />
```

The fragment is created in the coresponding class file:

```
public class LiveMeeting_meeting_fragment extends Fragment {

Button sp;
Button stop;
Chronometer chrono;
int cnt = 0;
long timeStop;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.livemeeting_meeting_fragment, container, false);
    sp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp_live_meeting);
    stop = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stop_live_meeting);
    chrono = (Chronometer) rootView.findViewById(R.id.live_timer);
    return rootView;
}

public void sp_timer(View view){
    if(cnt == 0){
        sp.setText("Pause meeting");
        chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeStop);
        chrono.start();
        cnt = 1;
    } else if (cnt == 1){
        sp.setText("Continue meeting");
        chrono.stop();
        timeStop = chrono.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        cnt = 0;
    }

}
}
```

My problem is now, that I'm not able to call the function because it's telling me that it can't find the function:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sp_timer(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'sp_live_meeting'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't use that `onClick` attribute. It can only work for Activities. Set the click method manually with `View#setOnClickListener()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete your `onClick` attribute from XML and instead use `onClickListener`.

Code:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //write your sp_timer method here
    }
});
```

Android looks for the `onClick` method `sp_timer()` only in the current Activity. This is important to remember if you are using fragments, since even if you add the XML above using a fragment, Android will not look for the `onClick` method in the .java file of the fragment used to add the XML.